# Live Apache Log Viewer?

Tags: logging, apache-2.2

Is there any type of program or installable web interface that can display apache access and error logs *live*. I know there are a few interfaces that use the `modstatus` module, but I guess I am asking which is the best. I am running a WAMP (Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5, MySQL) server on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup a local instance of [this script](http://commavee.com/2007/04/13/ajax-logfile-tailer-viewer/) on a dev server for quick access to the log file.  I can't comment on how robust it is in general, but for me using it to quickly diagnose an error it hasn't given me any problems.